# preconditioned matrix with golden ratio, golden ratio conjugate, and 1 as eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, numerical-linear-algebra

I have a symmetric positive definite (SPD) matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and a full-rank matrix $B\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$.

I need to show that the pre-conditioned matrix $\begin{bmatrix}
   A       & 0 \\
    0       & BA^{-1}B^T
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}
   A       & B^T \\
    B      & 0
\end{bmatrix}$
has only three eigenvalues, $1, (1\pm\sqrt{5})/2,$ and I need to find their multiplicity.

I do not understand why this problem is interesting or how it was created. Why does the golden ratio appear at all here? I also do not know how to get such specific eigenvalues from such a seemingly-general matrix.

Comment: By "SPD", do you mean "symmetric, positive definite"?

Comment: Did you mean $B\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$?

Comment: Regarding why the problem is interesting and how it was created, we could probably be more helpful there if you told us where you encountered this problem in the first place.

Comment: I encountered it in course notes for my numerical linear algebra class in the section on Schur complement.  I do not understand how this problem relates to anything or is useful, though.  It seems random.

Comment: So, the matrix on the right is a classical example of a saddle point matrix which arise in various applications. E.g., in discretizations based on mixed f.e. methods. The matrix on the left is a general example of a preconditioner based on the Schur complement. Which is quite topical in iterative methods.

Comment: Can you tell us what’s the textbook for your course?

Comment: It is not a published textbook, just class notes.

Comment: You can find the full eigenvalue-eigenvector analysis in Theorem 3.3 [here](http://page.math.tu-berlin.de/~liesen/Publicat/DesLie05.pdf).

Comment: What do you mean? The proof of the theorem takes half of a page and is very self-contained (does not refer to anything else in the paper or other papers). You need maybe a bit adapt your notation but that's all.

Comment: How can I find the eigenvalues' multiplicities?